# How to show only the apps active in current desktop on Mac

Tags: macos

I love using the virtual desktops on Mac to separate what I'm working on at any time of day.  However, I would really like for the Dock to only show the apps that are current to the desktop that I'm working on.  As an example, if I'm using a text editor and terminal in the current desktop, I would like for those to be the only items on the dock.  Is that possible?

Comment: These questions are better be posted on another site, probably Superuser.

Comment: If I was going to ask this question, which is probably off-topic here, I'd ask it at https://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You could do this manually.  Right clicking on a doc icon allows you to remove it. I don't know of any way to automate this.

Comment: I am still looking for an answer :(